# Command and Option keys on Windows keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I am using an external keyboard which is a Windows keyboard. I am not able to use copy and paste command with ctrl and there is no command key or the option key in this keyboard. What is the shorcut for copy paste or cut paste on such keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows key will operate as the Command key, so cmd-c is win-c.

Further, the Alt key will operate as the Option key.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS the copy command is invoked by the key combo `command` + `C`. The Windows key is normally the `command` key. As your keyboard does not have a command key you can map that key behavior to another key.

To swap the behavior of keys, go to `System Preferences` --> `Keyboard` --> `Modifier Keys`, select the right keyboard and set the desired behavior per key.

An option would be to set your `alt` \ `option` key to act like `command` and have your `Caps Lock` act like `alt` \ `option`.

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to set more advanced key remaps.